# Qt Creator showing multiple times in "open file with" menu in Windows 11

Tags: windows, qt, menu, uninstallation

I used Qt creator to make a UI for a python project a while ago. I then proceeded to uninstall Qt using the correct uninstaller to remove everything properly.

Now, whenever I want to select an application to open any file (be it json, png, mp4, ...), Qt creator appears 18 times in my "open file with" menu, which is a bit annoying because:

A) it is supposed to be uninstalled.
B) I have to scroll down each time to find the app I want.

I am using Windows 11, version 10.0.22621 Build 22621.

[image: "open file with" menu]

I tried:

- Looking for the specified location in the screenshot, but nothing was there, it was correctly removed by Qt's uninstaller.
- Resetting the default application
- Looking into my application to see if there were remnants of Qt creator, I found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it using CCleaner's registry option.